# Building a custom terraform provider errors out

Tags: go, terraform

I am hitting this error while i try to compile GO code

```
[root@scsor0014444001 Netapp]# go build -o terraform-provider-xxxx
# github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config
../go/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config/testing.go:9: t.Helper undefined (type *testing.T has no field or method Helper)

[root@scsor0014444001 Netapp]# go version
go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64
```

Can someone help me in understanding whats wrong here ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may happen if you use go < 1.9 (see [Developing Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform#developing-terraform))

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#test-helper

Answer (score 1):

As of the 0.10.3 release, Terraform core now requires Go 1.9 due to the use of the new "test helper" feature.

Since providers depend on some packages from the core system as libraries, this dependency is unfortunately then inherited by the providers too. If you're using *vendoring* to make Terraform core available to the provider (recommended!) then you can potentially wind back the vendored version to [the final commit before this change](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/commit/b6047dcf9ee42abc415fe769ed5ef643972f6aef) in order to build with 1.8, though over time this strategy will of course cause the vendored package to fall behind the latest changes.

Upgrading Go to 1.9 should address this in a more permanent way.